# Need to save a value from javascript variable to php session

Tags: javascript, php

```
   <div id="fbcontainer" style="margin:50px">

<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/PTP-574862402690345/?ref=bookmarks"  send="false" layout="box_count" width="450" show_faces="true" font="verdana"></fb:like>

 <strong id="login">

 <span id="login-mask"></span>

 <a id="fb-login" href="#" onclick="FB.login()">Please Login with Facebook first!</a>

</strong>

</div>


<div id="after"><input type="submit" id="submit" class="take-quiz-btn index-btn redglow" value="Start" />

</div>
<input type="text" id="loc" name="loc" value="<?php echo @$_SESSION['quiz'];?>">




        </div>                        
    </form>
```

Want to save a value in php session variable on like click and change the session value when user again dislikes to show and hide the start button.As when user likes and refresh the page the button disappears this should be avoided.

```
var app_id = 'appid';
local = document.getElementById('loc').value;


window.onload = function(){

if (local=="") {
$('#after').css({"display":"none"});
console.log("1");
console.log("local1="+local);


} 
else{
 $('#after').css({"display":"block"});
 console.log("2");
 console.log("local2="+local);


 }
 }

(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="+app_id;
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));





  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  appId : app_id, // App ID
  status : true, // check login status
  cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   xfbml : true // parse XFBML

  });



 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
 function(response) {$('#after').css({"display":"block"});
 //$('#local').val('assign');
 //<?php $_SESSION['quiz'] = "assign"; ?>
  local="assign";
  local = <?php $_SESSION['quiz']; ?>
   console.log("3");
   console.log("local3="+local);
  alert(local); 
  }
  );



  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
  function(response) {$('#after').css({"display":"none"});
  // $('#local').val('assign');
   // <?php $_SESSION['quiz'] = ""; ?>
    local="";
   local = <?php $_SESSION['quiz']; ?>
   console.log("4");
   console.log("local4="+local);
   alert(local);        

    }
   );



    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {

    window.location.reload();

     });





    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {



    if (response.status === 'connected') {



     // user is logged in and has authenticated your app

    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;

    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;



    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {



   // user is logged in but has not authenticated your app

    console.log('Logged in no auth');



  } else {




    $('#login').fadeIn();

    $('#login-mask').fadeIn();

    console.log('NOT Logged in');



    }

   });



 $('#login-mask').live('click',function() {

 $('#fb-login').effect('shake', { times:3 }, 300);

 });

 };
```

Comment: Perhaps it is an idea to create a seperate cookie for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Done Using Ajax

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
 function(response) {$('#after').css({"display":"block"});
 $.ajax({
   url:"ajax.php",
   type:"post",
   data:{"type":"change"},
   success:function(data){

       console.log("change="+data);
   }



  });

  }
 );


     FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
    function(response) {$('#after').css({"display":"none"});

    $.ajax({
   url:"ajax.php",
   type:"post",
   data:{"type":"again"},
   success:function(data){

       console.log("again="+data);
   }
   });
 console.log("4");
  }
);
```

php:-

```
  @$type = $_REQUEST['type'];


  if($type == "change"){


$_SESSION['quiz'] = "assign";

echo $_SESSION['quiz'];

 }


 if($type == "again"){


 $_SESSION['quiz'] = "";

 echo $_SESSION['quiz'];

}


 ?>
```